# How to access first or specific object from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file with below mentioned format

mydata.json

```
{
    "nodes":{
        "Aidan":{"color":"green", "shape":"dot", "alpha":1, "id" : "aidan"},
        "Sofia":{"color":"green", "shape":"dot", "alpha":1},
        "Liam":{"color":"GoldenRod", "shape":"dot", "alpha":1}
    },
    "edges":{
        "Quinn":{
            "Liam":{"length":2.5,"weight":2},
            "Audrey":{"length":2.5,"weight":2},
            "Noah":{"length":2.5,"weight":2},
            "Claire":{"length":2.5,"weight":2}
        },
        "Liam":{
            "Sofia":{"length":2.5,"weight":2},
            "Ethan":{"length":2.5,"weight":2},
            "Amelia":{"length":2.5,"weight":2}
        }
    }
}
```

I will be reading above file data using jquery as mentioned below

```
var data = $.getJSON("data/mydata.json",function(data){
    var nodes = data.nodes;
    var edges = data.edges;

    //i want to access first element or between element.
    //like var edge = edges.get(0) or nodes.get("aidan")
})
```

I want to access first element or between element with the index or by name property of object. like var edge = edges.get(0) or nodes.get("aidan").

Thanks

Comment: There is no "first" element, it's all objects, and there is no order in objects, only keys and values. In other words, there is no guarantee that one key / value pair appears before another. To get the value of a key, use dot or bracket notation, not jQuery methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it

```
Object.keys(nodes)[0]; //retrieve the first key
edges['Quinn'];
edges.Quinn
```

A little warning on the first one, Object in JS are unordered so it may break, thus browser tends to keep the insertion order.
hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
nodes['aidan']
edges['Quinn']
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the before mentioned code

```
nodes['aidan']
```

or

```
nodes.aidan
```

should work equally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared a [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ghp3/1/) for you. You can check there.